# How can I fit images with different resolutions?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How can I fit and then overlay 2 images which have different resolution ?

This is the main image:
[image: image description]

I have this one, which has the correct mesh to the image above:

[image: image description]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('transparency.jpg')

img2 = cv2.imread('La1.png')


row1,cols1, ch1 = img1.shape
row2,cols2, ch2 = img2.shape

res = cv2.resize(img2, None , fx = (1.* row1 /row2 ), fy =(1.* cols1 /cols2 ), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty unclear from your question how it is supposed to come out! I am just doing this at the command line using ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows - there are Python bindings if that floats your boat though.

Anyway, let's get the size of the images:

```
identify m*

main.png PNG 1790x4098 1790x4098+0+0 8-bit sRGB 942KB 0.000u 0:00.000
mesh.jpg JPEG 2537x5703 2537x5703+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.493MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

So, let's load up the main image and resize it to match the mesh. Then let's load up the mesh, and make everything transparent that is within 10% of white - that will leave just the black lines from the mesh. But we can't see black on black, so let's make the black lines in the mesh red. Then splat that (technical term meaning *"composite"*) on top of the main image:

```
convert main.png -resize 2537x5703! \( mesh.jpg -fuzz 10% -transparent white -fill red -colorize 100% \) -composite result.png
```

Here's what you get.

[image]

Looks like your mesh needs cropping down the left side to shift it over, so try:

```
convert main.png -resize 2480x5703! \( mesh.jpg -crop +57 -fuzz 10% -transparent white -fill red -colorize 100% \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Wheh I try to colorize the mesh, it colorizes even the background (which should be transparent) instead of putting red only at the lines .
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try making the fuzz 25% or so

Comment: Thank you, I add to use anoter command to change colors and it worked.
However, When I changed the "image sources" to https://meocloud.pt/link/feadfebe-4290-4988-9d47-7dc78ce99eeb/testImage/ I wasn't able to get similar results.
The command that I used was: convert main.png -resize 10019x22807! \( mesh.png -trim -fuzz 10% -transparent white -fill red -opaque "rgb(0,0,0)" \) -composite result.png

Comment: That one seems to need a fuzz of 60%

Comment: I think the problem is on the "trim". The bounds don't match

Comment: do you know another way to try to match images? Its seams hard to fit the mesh with the layer :\

Comment: Two questions... 1) How many do you have to do? 2) Ignoring the edges, will the main (fat) outline of the buildings in the meshes always fit exactly - or could they be say too wide but not tall enough to match? I'm trying to understand if the meshes need rotating or scaling horizontally or vertically of maybe both?

Comment: I'll have 4 different layers(main files) to 1 mesh.They won't perfect match.
However the mesh has the boundaries and the correct shape.
The layers do not have the perfect shape. They would be like your example above

Comment: It sounds like it would be easier to do it in Photoshop by eye if you only have 4.

Comment: I'd like to have in a script, it is easier to automate.
here they are: https://meocloud.pt/link/feadfebe-4290-4988-9d47-7dc78ce99eeb/testImage/https://meocloud.pt/link/feadfebe-4290-4988-9d47-7dc78ce99eeb/testImage/

Comment: I cannot do the same thing with crop option. It creates a ton of images. Did you use any script ?

Comment: When you use `-crop`, you should give a width and height **AND AN OFFSET** else you will get lots - so `convert image.png -crop WxH+X+Y`

Comment: But here : "mesh.jpg -crop +57 ..." you just used +57

Comment: ... which is an offset because it has a plus in front.

Comment: Ok, I got it. It's not trivial overlay both images.
Essentially, because I'm creating the mesh image using matplotlib.
I "just" want to overlay 2 different images. I made a questions in order to try changing the problem approach without success http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388632/how-can-i-draw-the-triangle-mesh-having-the-points-coordinates-using-opencv.